# cesium how to get frustumOutlineGeometry coordinate

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to set Cesium FrustumGeometry far face material，but How should i get FrustumGeometry far face coordinate？

I want to achieve this effect：

[image: picture]

```js
    pyramidBorder.current = new Cesium.Primitive({
      geometryInstances: new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
        geometry: new Cesium.FrustumOutlineGeometry({
          origin: position,
          orientation: Cesium.Quaternion.fromHeadingPitchRoll(new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, roll), new Cesium.Quaternion()),
          frustum: frustum,
        }),
        releaseGeometryInstances:false,
        attributes: {
          color: Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(
            Cesium.Color.fromAlpha(Cesium.defaultValue(Cesium.Color.YELLOW, Cesium.Color.CYAN), opacity, new Cesium.Color())
          ),
        },
        id: 'pyramidBorder',
      }),
      appearance: new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance({
        translucent: false,
        flat: true,
        closed: false
      }),
      asynchronous: false,
    })
```